# Is there an ldap server implementation that can query smtp for usernames/passwords?

Tags: smtp, ldap

My organization does not have a central LDAP server, but they do have a mail server. Is there some software out there (open source, hopefully) that acts as an LDAP server on the front end, but can query an SMTP instance on the fly to populate with users and passwords and present that as LDAP?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the shell backend of OpenLdap to do that.

Basically you write a shell or Perl script that queries whatever other system you have and hook it up to openldap.

See:
http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/backends.html

Comment: Hey schlenk, thanks for answering. I am on the cusp of writing a solution myself in Ruby using ruby-ldapserver, but wanted to see if there was a drop-in replacement so I could spare myself the trouble. Might be easier to do a ruby backend and OL frontend, so I'll look into that.